# Extracting monthly band data from an image collection from a pixel with 1000 sample points into a table as CSV - not as chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, fields-attributes, google-earth-engine-python-api, value-extraction, propertyname

I have 1000 field samples as points.
I would like to Extract band values from ERA5land which is already monthly aggregated for each of the points
The data is stored in many bands,
I have selected my bands of interest.
I have difficulty in exporting the band value per each point, and naming them per month.
[image: I would like my results to look like the image below].
Here is my code so far:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR')
                  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR')
  .select([
    'temperature_2m',
    'soil_temperature_level_1',
    'soil_temperature_level_2',
    'soil_temperature_level_3',
    'soil_temperature_level_4',
    'volumetric_soil_water_layer_1',
    'volumetric_soil_water_layer_2',
    'volumetric_soil_water_layer_3',
    'volumetric_soil_water_layer_4',
    'evaporation_from_bare_soil_sum',
    'evaporation_from_vegetation_transpiration_sum',
    'potential_evaporation_sum',
    'total_evaporation_sum',
    'total_precipitation_sum',
    'leaf_area_index_low_vegetation',
    'soil_temperature_level_1_min',
    'soil_temperature_level_2_min',
    'soil_temperature_level_3_min',
    'soil_temperature_level_4_min',
    'soil_temperature_level_1_max',
    'soil_temperature_level_2_max',
    'soil_temperature_level_3_max',
    'soil_temperature_level_4_max'
  ])
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31'));



var visualization = {
  bands: ['temperature_2m'],
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  palette: [
    '000080', '0000d9', '4000ff', '8000ff', '0080ff', '00ffff',
    '00ff80', '80ff00', 'daff00', 'ffff00', 'fff500', 'ffda00',
    'ffb000', 'ffa400', 'ff4f00', 'ff2500', 'ff0a00', 'ff00ff',
  ]
};

Map.setCenter(70, 45, 3);
Map.addLayer(
    dataset, visualization, 'ERA5', true, 0.8);


function zonalStats(ic, fc, params) {
  // Initialize internal params dictionary.
  var _params = {
    reducer: null,
    scale: 11132,
    crs: null,
    bands: [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
    bandsRename: [
'temperature_2m','soil_temperature_level_1', 'soil_temperature_level_2', 'soil_temperature_level_3', 'soil_temperature_level_4',
'volumetric_soil_water_layer_1', 'volumetric_soil_water_layer_2', 'volumetric_soil_water_layer_3', 'volumetric_soil_water_layer_4',
'evaporation_from_bare_soil_sum', 'evaporation_from_vegetation_transpiration_sum', 'potential_evaporation_sum', 'total_evaporation_sum',
'total_precipitation_sum','leaf_area_index_low_vegetation','soil_temperature_level_1_min', 'soil_temperature_level_2_min', 'soil_temperature_level_3_min', 'soil_temperature_level_4_min',
'soil_temperature_level_1_max', 'soil_temperature_level_2_max', 'soil_temperature_level_3_max', 'soil_temperature_level_4_max'],
    imgProps: null,
    imgPropsRename: null,
    datetimeName: 'datetime',
    datetimeFormat: 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
  };

  // Replace initialized params with provided params.
  if (params) {
    for (var param in params) {
      _params[param] = params[param] || _params[param];
    }
  }

  // Set default parameters based on an image representative.
  var imgRep = ic.first();
  var nonSystemImgProps = ee.Feature(null)
    .copyProperties(imgRep).propertyNames();
  if (!_params.bands) _params.bands = imgRep.bandNames();
  if (!_params.bandsRename) _params.bandsRename = _params.bands;
  if (!_params.imgProps) _params.imgProps = nonSystemImgProps;
  if (!_params.imgPropsRename) _params.imgPropsRename = _params.imgProps;

  // Map the reduceRegions function over the image collection.
  var results = ic.map(function(img) {
    // Select bands (optionally rename), set a datetime & timestamp property.
    img = ee.Image(img.select(_params.bands, _params.bandsRename))
      .set(_params.datetimeName, img.date().format(_params.datetimeFormat))
      .set('timestamp', img.get('system:time_start'));

    // Define final image property dictionary to set in output features.
    var propsFrom = ee.List(_params.imgProps)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var propsTo = ee.List(_params.imgPropsRename)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var imgProps = img.toDictionary(propsFrom).rename(propsFrom, propsTo);

    // Subset points that intersect the given image.
    var fcSub = fc.filterBounds(img.geometry());

    // Reduce the image by regions.
    return img.reduceRegions({
      collection: fcSub,
      reducer: _params.reducer,
      scale: _params.scale,
      crs: _params.crs
    })
    // Add metadata to each feature.
    .map(function(f) {
      return f.set(imgProps);
    });
  }).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.notNull(_params.bandsRename));

// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var ptsTopoStats = zonalStats(dataset, points, _params);
print(ptsTopoStats);

Map.addLayer(ptsTopoStats)
return results;
}
```

Here is a link to my code : https://code.earthengine.google.com/24f98d55f1576f6e35711fe983f31181